# Returning an object with a list inside

Tags: c#, .net, json, api

I have two classes.

```
public class ItemClass
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
        public int prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemClassList
    {
        public string listName;
        public int listCount;
        public List<ItemClass> list;
    }
```

and the Api method

```
        [HttpGet("Items")]
        public ActionResult GetItems()
        {
            List<ItemClass> _result = new List<ItemClass>
            {
                new ItemClass() { prop1 = "test1", prop2 = 1 },
                new ItemClass() { prop1 = "test2", prop2 = 2 },
                new ItemClass() { prop1 = "test3", prop2 = 3 }
            };

            var _resultList = new ItemClassList()
            {
                listName = "Items list",
                listCount = _result.Count,
                list = _result
            };

            return Ok(_resultList);
        }
```

In my API, I want to return an '_resultList', but I only return an '{}'.
If I return object '_result' then JSON is correct.
How should I prepare the object '_resultList' for return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to made into properties to be serialised correctly.

Add a { get; set; } after each of the properties of ItemClassList and you should get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

at first step you should set {get ; set ;} for properties in ItemClassList.

then don't forget to do this :

```
var _resultList = new ItemClassList()
        {
            listName = "Items list",
            listCount = _result.Count,
            list = new List<ItemClass>()
        };

_resultList.list.AddRange(_result );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. 
Why do you suggest creating a new object and copying data. If I destroy this object in a moment ?
What is better 'list = new List<ItemClass>()' than 'list = _result' ?

Comment: if you want to put data to an object of course you should create a new instance of it.
an object or list of object inside of the other should init , too.